# how to combine many google sheets in one sheet by using query

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I created two online sheets and tried to collect them in another one sheet by query but there a missing data although it's exists in the original sheets (data sources), so why that query hide some data and leave the others.

```
=QUERY({importrange("1xytv1Cl2ANXZP4paiNn4Zejvgl2BBKOLgbdEqeYL_KM","After Sales!A1:AI10");importrange("1gmimVYQQeN_v7sl6yyyvPdN6FkIO7NYADvTf6tGj2-k","Sales!A1:AI10")},"Select * Where Col1 is not null",1))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Kindly include the formula you used in your post above.

Comment: =QUERY({importrange("1xytv1Cl2ANXZP4paiNn4Zejvgl2BBKOLgbdEqeYL_KM","After Sales!A1:AI10");importrange("1gmimVYQQeN_v7sl6yyyvPdN6FkIO7NYADvTf6tGj2-k","Sales!A1:AI10")},"Select * Where Col1 is not null",1)

Comment: You can edit your post by clicking the `Edit` button below the tags and include that formula. Also, It is hard to replicate your issue since the sample data in your image  does not cover the whole range you provided in your formula. I would suggest sharing a dummy spreadsheet with sample data. See [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: i've improved my code formatting, could you vote up my question now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(TO_TEXT({
 IMPORTRANGE("1xytv1Cl2ANXZP4paiNn4Zejvgl2BBKOLgbdEqeYL_KM", "After Sales!A1:AI10");
 IMPORTRANGE("1gmimVYQQeN_v7sl6yyyvPdN6FkIO7NYADvTf6tGj2-k", "Sales!A1:AI10")}), 
 "where Col1 is not null", 1))
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, i realy can't find words to describe hot to thank you :)
could you explaine to me what was the issue exactly to avoiid it in the future??

Comment: @MahmoudBadr the issue is within QUERY. when there is mixed dataset (numbers and plain text) query starts to make (incorect) "assumptions" so if column contains majority of number it will skip the text and vice versa. TO_TEXT() will force the dataset to be formated in one type

Comment: Thank you very much